# C# OpenTK GLControl drawing cube incorrect

Tags: c#, winforms, opengl, glsl, opentk

I use OpenTK's GLControl in C# WinForm (.NET Framework) Application,
but I don't know why my 20mm3 cube scaled alone with my form.

I inherit GLControl with DCGLControl and add GL.Viewport(ClientRectangle) when control resize :

```
private void DCGLControl_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GL.Viewport(ClientRectangle);
    Matrix4 projection = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView((float)Math.PI / 4, Width / (float)Height, 1.0f, 1000f);
    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
    GL.LoadMatrix(ref projection);
}
```

And here is my DCGLControl_Load event (initialize something and start a new thread to render it):

```
private void DCGLControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
    GL.ClearColor(ClearColor);
    Resize += DCGLControl_Resize;

    Matrix4 trans;
    trans = Matrix4.CreateScale(0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f);

    Context.MakeCurrent(null);
    renderThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        Context.MakeCurrent(WindowInfo);
        while (true)
        {
            int n;
            for (n = 0; n < Models.Count; n++)
                if (Models[n].VAO == 0)
                {
                    Models[n].Shader.Compile();
                    GenVAO(Models[n]);
                }
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
            GL.Viewport(ClientRectangle);


            for (n = 0; n < Models.Count; n++)
            {
                GL.BindVertexArray(Models[n].VAO);

                Models[n].Shader.Use();
                Models[n].Shader.SetMatrix4("transform", trans);

                if (Models[n].UseEBO)
                    GL.DrawElements(Models[n].PrimitiveType, Models[n].DrawOrder.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);
                else
                    GL.DrawArrays(Models[n].PrimitiveType, 0, Models[n].Vertices.Length);
            }
            SwapBuffers();
            Thread.Sleep(1000/60);
        }
    });

    renderThread.Start();
}
```

And here is my vertex shader :

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal;

uniform mat4 transform;

void main()
{
    gl_Position =  transform * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

I got result like this :
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaPa1.png)

I am a beginner with OpenGL and OpenTK, thanks for help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix the fixed function matrices with the matrix transformations in 3.30 core shader. This means that the instruction `GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);` has no effect (except an OpenGL error in a core profile context). You have to add a projection matrix to the shader:

```c
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 transform;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * transform * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Add an attribute for the projection matrix:

```cs
private Matrix4 projection;
```

Set the matrix in the `DCGLControl_Resize` callback:

```cs
private void DCGLControl_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GL.Viewport(ClientRectangle);
    self.projection = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView((float)Math.PI / 4, Width / (float)Height, 1.0f, 1000f);
}
```

Set the matrix uniform before drawing the geoemtry:

```cs
GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
GL.Viewport(ClientRectangle);

for (n = 0; n < Models.Count; n++)
{
    GL.BindVertexArray(Models[n].VAO);

    Models[n].Shader.Use();
    Models[n].Shader.SetMatrix4("projection", self.projection);
    Models[n].Shader.SetMatrix4("transform", trans);

    if (Models[n].UseEBO)
        GL.DrawElements(Models[n].PrimitiveType, Models[n].DrawOrder.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);
    else
        GL.DrawArrays(Models[n].PrimitiveType, 0, Models[n].Vertices.Length);
}
SwapBuffers();
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but when I add the projection, all object in the scene are disappear (nothing show on my view port), do you need other info of my code ?

Comment: @HarugaHarumi This is another issue. Very likely the objects are clipped by the near plane of the perspective projection. Note the objects need to be drawn between the near and far plane of the [Viewing frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum). You must shift the objects along the negative z axis. (e.g. translate -5 along the z axis)

Comment: So, if my cude vertices is (0,0,0) to (20, 20, 20), it will invisible ? or I still can see some face of it ?

Comment: @HarugaHarumi It is invisible. Try the range from (0, 0, -10) to (20, 20, -30)

Comment: @ Rabbid76 It appear in my viewport, thank you very much !!
but now when I resize my control height, cube scaled with it, but resize width.
Is it correct ?

Comment: @HarugaHarumi Yes. The filed  of view angle (`(float)Math.PI / 4`) is measured along the y axis.

Comment: Thanks, I suddenly found the most problem was because I set the Matrix4 with GL.UniformMatrix4 set transpose to true, and this waste me three week XD. Although they work now, but I still don't understand what it means